# getting value of update input with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, forms

Im developing Html Form where value will update using jquery as user input the value.

[image]

When you enter value in Enter Your Value field it will instantly update its price in Price field

Now i want to add all field sum which will be field 1,field 2,field 3,field 4,field 5 and field 6 and display the total sum in Total Amount but total calculation of the all field are not updating in Total Amount.

**Html Code**

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="FUll Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3 menier">
            <h4>Iron Bark:</h4>
            $210 Per Cubic Metre 
            <input type="number" id="ironbark" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
            <div class="mt-3">
                Price 
            <input id="ironbarvalue" type="text" name="ironbark" class="total-amount form-control"  readonly>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
          <div class="mb-3 menier">
            <h4>Red Gum:</h4>
            $200 Per Cubic Metre 
            <input type="number" id="redgum" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
            <div class="mt-3">
              <span class="sammy">Price </span>
            
            <input type="text" id="redgumvalue" name="redgum" class="total-amount form-control"  readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3 menier">
            <h4>Mixed Gum:</h4>
            $100 Per Cubic Metre 
            <input type="number" id="mixedgum"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
            <div class="mt-3">
            Price <input id="mixedgumvalue" type="text" name="mixedgum" class="total-amount form-control"  readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3 menier">
            <h4>Brown Bark:</h4>
            $110 Per Cubic Metre <input id="brownbark" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
            <div class="mt-3">
            Price <input id="brownbarkvalue" type="text" name="brownbark" class="total-amount form-control"   readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="stackfee" name="stackingfee" value="25">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Stacking Fee: $25 Per m3 </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="delivery" name="deliveryfee" value="50">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Delivery Fee: $50 Minimum  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <strong class="">
          Total Amount: $
          </strong>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total-amount" id="sum" name="totalsum" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#ironbark').change(function(){
    var ironbarkrate = parseFloat($('#ironbark').val()) || 0;
    $('#ironbarvalue').attr('value', 210 * ironbarkrate);    
  });

  $('#redgum').change(function(){
    var redgum = parseFloat($('#redgum').val()) || 0;
    $('#redgumvalue').attr('value', 200 * redgum);    
  });

  $('#mixedgum').change(function(){
    var mixedgum = parseFloat($('#mixedgum').val()) || 0;
    $('#mixedgumvalue').attr('value', 100 * mixedgum);    
  });

  $('#brownbark').change(function(){
    var brownbark = parseFloat($('#brownbark').val()) || 0;
    $('#brownbarkvalue').attr('value', 110 * brownbark);   

  });

  $('#ironbarvalue, #redgumvalue,#mixedgumvalue,#brownbarkvalue').change(function(){
        var value1 = parseFloat($('#ironbarvalue').val()) || 0;
        var value2 = parseFloat($('#redgumvalue').val()) || 0;
        var value3 = parseFloat($('#mixedgumvalue').val()) || 0;
        var value4 = parseFloat($('#brownbarkvalue').val()) || 0;
        var value5 = parseFloat($('#stackfee').val()) || 0;
        var value6 = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()) || 0;
        $('#sum').attr('value',value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value5);
   });

});
```

Im Trying to get All sum on Total Amount… but im notable to get Sum display in Total Amount, isnt because Price field is generate by Jquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a common function to calculate the sum and you need to call it in each input `change` and checkbox `click` event like below:

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ironbark').change(function() {
    $('#ironbarvalue').val(210 * (parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0));
    calculateSum();
  });

  $('#redgum').change(function() {
    var redgum = parseFloat($('#redgum').val()) || 0;
    $('#redgumvalue').val(200 * (parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0));
    calculateSum();
  });

  $('#mixedgum').change(function() {
    $('#mixedgumvalue').val(100 * (parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0));
    calculateSum();
  });

  $('#brownbark').change(function() {
    $('#brownbarkvalue').val(110 * (parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0));
    calculateSum();

  });
  
  $('#stackfee').click(function() {
     calculateSum();
  });
  
  $('#delivery').click(function() {
     calculateSum();
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var value1 = parseFloat($('#ironbarvalue').val()) || 0;
  var value2 = parseFloat($('#redgumvalue').val()) || 0;
  var value3 = parseFloat($('#mixedgumvalue').val()) || 0;
  var value4 = parseFloat($('#brownbarkvalue').val()) || 0;
  var value5 = ($('#stackfee').is(":checked")) ? parseFloat($('#stackfee').val()) : 0;
  var value6 = ($('#delivery').is(":checked")) ? parseFloat($('#delivery').val()) : 0;
  $('#sum').val(value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="FUll Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3 menier">
        <h4>Iron Bark:</h4>
        $210 Per Cubic Metre
        <input type="number" id="ironbark" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
        <div class="mt-3">
          Price
          <input id="ironbarvalue" type="text" name="ironbark" class="total-amount form-control" readonly>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
      <div class="mb-3 menier">
        <h4>Red Gum:</h4>
        $200 Per Cubic Metre
        <input type="number" id="redgum" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <span class="sammy">Price </span>

          <input type="text" id="redgumvalue" name="redgum" class="total-amount form-control" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3 menier">
        <h4>Mixed Gum:</h4>
        $100 Per Cubic Metre
        <input type="number" id="mixedgum" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
        <div class="mt-3">
          Price <input id="mixedgumvalue" type="text" name="mixedgum" class="total-amount form-control" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3 menier">
        <h4>Brown Bark:</h4>
        $110 Per Cubic Metre <input id="brownbark" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Value">
        <div class="mt-3">
          Price <input id="brownbarkvalue" type="text" name="brownbark" class="total-amount form-control" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="stackfee" name="stackingfee" value="25">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Stacking Fee: $25 Per m3 </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="delivery" name="deliveryfee" value="50">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Delivery Fee: $50 Minimum  </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <strong class="">
          Total Amount: $
          </strong>
      <input type="number" class="form-control total-amount" id="sum" name="totalsum" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

getting too many **id** is problematic, use $(**document**) to select all and use **$('#sum').val()** to enter the total value.

```
$(document).change(function(){
    var value1 = parseFloat($('#ironbarvalue').val()) || 0;
    var value2 = parseFloat($('#redgumvalue').val()) || 0;
    var value3 = parseFloat($('#mixedgumvalue').val()) || 0;
    var value4 = parseFloat($('#brownbarkvalue').val()) || 0;
    var value5 = parseFloat($('#stackfee').val()) || 0;
    var value6 = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()) || 0;
    $('#sum').val(value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value5);
});
```

Comment: but i need addition from different input field.... how can i get that one without id.....

Comment: thank you, for taking time to review my problem, its exactly what im trying to get

Comment: @majan `$('#stackfee').val()` and `$('#delivery').val()` will always add their corresponding value irrespective of whether these boxes are checked or not. Please take a look at my answer. I handled that and described it too.